# Log shipping from SQL Server Managed Instance to a database on a Virtual Machine, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

We are looking into Managed Instances as a step forward from Availability Groups on Azure VMs. One of the features we are using now is log shipping from AG primary to an instance that is not a member of the AG (for heavy reporting).
I have found Log Replay Service (LRS) as an option to use but it looks like it is just an one way option to move a database from On Prem db to Managed Instance.
Another thing is Replication, but it is not doing the whole DB, just tables.

Is there something else that exists as an option to keep a copy of the database updated out of Managed Instance itself?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I don't think that title and body are opposite but let me clarify.

What we have now is log shipping from an AG instance to a stand alone SQL Server instance.

In the future we would like to have something like log shipping from a Managed Instance again to a stand alone SQL Server instance. To replace current AG cluster with a single Managed Instance.

To end up with a single Managed Instance + stand alone SQL Server instance for reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the future we would like to have something like log shipping from a Managed Instance again to a stand alone SQL Server instance.

The docs on [Features comparison: Azure SQL Database and **Azure SQL Managed Instance**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/features-comparison?view=azuresql#features-of-sql-database-and-sql-managed-instance) state the following for each type of data synchronization / data tracking feature:

- Active-Geo Replication

> No

- Always On Availability Groups:

> SQL Server instances and SQL Database can't be used as secondaries for SQL Managed Instance.

- Change Data Capture (CDC)

> Yes

- Database Mirroring

> No

- DDL and DML Triggers

> Yes

- Ledger

> No

- Log Shipping

> Not available as a replication mechanism between databases

- Restore database to SQL Server

> Yes, to SQL Server 2022 only.

- SQL Data Sync

> No

- SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)

> Yes, with a managed SSIS in Azure Data Factory (ADF) environment, where packages are stored in SSISDB hosted by SQL Managed Instance and executed on Azure SSIS Integration Runtime (IR), see [Create Azure-SSIS IR in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-ssis-integration-runtime).

- Transactional Replication

> Yes (public preview) - see [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server?view=azuresql#replication)

- Windows Server Failover Cluster

> No

Based on all of the above, your options are severely limited and likely will require a lot of work to set something up. Essentially your options are the following, in order of my preference based on difficulty in implementing, maintaining, and reliability:

1. **Restore database to SQL Server** - If your VM SQL Server instance happens to be SQL Server 2022 and you can tolerate stale data between backups, then this will likely be your most simplest and reliable option to implement. You'll need to roll your own job (perhaps a SQL Agent Job that leverages a Linked Server) to actually routinely do the restore, of course.
2. **Transactional Replication** - As long as the limitations aren't a deal breaker, and you are replicating between compatible versions (usually within ~3 versions between Publisher and Subscriber), this is probably the next simplest to configure, and generally works well, unless an oddity occurs that causes it to break. Then usually resolving that oddity and bouncing replication will get it working again. The only other drawbacks is if there are many (hundreds+) objects you need to replicate, that can be annoying to initially setup, and not every object of a database is able to be replicated. Specifically, tables without primary keys are not applicable for Transactional Replication. One workaround for that is to create an indexed view on top of the table, which will have a unique clustered index defined on it. Indexed views are applicable for replication. Of course, the data in the indexed view will need to be unique in order to add a unique clustered index to it.
3. **DDL and DML Triggers** - This will require the most work as it is the most manual route to go. But it also should be rather flexible and reliable. Unfortunately you'll find yourself probably needing to create at least one trigger for every table and view. And this doesn't necessarily help you maintain other object changes like stored procedures. You'll probably want to leverage a Linked Server to push the changes across to the SQL Server instance on the VM. This will definitely be a lot of work.
4. **Change Data Capture (CDC)** - This will be less work than #3 Triggers, but will likely have more overhead and is less flexible. It won't help you maintain most schema changes (e.g. if a view is changed), and will limit what changes are allowed to the tables that have it enabled. Enabling it for every table seems like a lot. And you'd have to roll your own job to migrate each logged change and apply them to the SQL Server instance. Triggers would almost make that job simpler but than you might as well use triggers all together and not use this option.
5. **SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)** - This is probably one of the more complicated options in regards to learning the technology and initially configuring. It's also a technology I personally feel is getting less and less use / attention over time, and one day may be on the features chopping block. But it's arguably a better route than Change Data Capture, to be honest. It was hard ranking these. It is more flexible and potentially less overhead than CDC, and once you get it initially configured properly and deployed, it *should* run with minimal issues and maintenance required.

Personally, I'd strive for either option #1 or #2 and strongly stay away from #4 and #5 if possible, with #3 being a tradeoff of how much work it would be to implement depending on what objects I want to keep synchronized between the two instances and how many of those objects exist in my database.

Comment: Thank you J.D., I was afraid it would be something like that.

We can't go with n.2 since we have many tables with no key.
Looks like option number 1 would be the best bet in our case.

I thought there would be something else, but then it beats the revenue they are making by pushing more replicas for the Managed Instance.

Thanks again.

Comment: @TheNixon No problem. Yea Cloud subjectively sucks these days for a multitude of reasons. Maybe in 5-10 years the options will be better. Regarding Transactional Replication, one workaround the table with no primary key issue is if you created an indexed view on top of it. The indexed view would have a unique clustered index on it, which makes the indexed view applicable for replication. Of course that's only possible if there is a uniquely defining set of columns in the indexed view (though it's rare and poor design for there to not be in the table). I've updated my answer to mention this